# Bug - "Share a link to this question via email, , , or .

Tags: bug

There is a weird bug with question sharing.
When I posted a question and scrolled down to the bottom of the page, I saw this obviously erroneous message:
[image: Error with link sharing]

Steps to reproduce this error:

1. Post a new question
2. Scroll down to the bottom of the page to find the text displayed above.

In case these steps do not reproduce the error, here is the link to my question where the error can be seen: [Number of iterations required for a transposition cipher to yield the original input](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2525587)

Comment: It looks fine here.  Maybe there's a quirk with how MSE interacts with your browser.

Comment: Looking at the page source code, I can see that all the links are there, but when I go to my browser, only the Email link shows up. I looked through the stylesheet for the page and found the following CSS: `.s-footer,#header,#hlinks,#hmenus,#nav,#sidebar,#system-message,#tabs,.aside-cta,.bounty-link,.comments-link,.notify,.post-comments,.post-menu,.top-bar,.tabs,div.vote,form,` **h2.bottom-notice** `,td.votecell,.newnav .tabs-list-container .tabs-list .intellitab` **{display:none}**

Comment: It looks fine to me as well. (Your linked page.)  But then, I didn't ask your question, so maybe it's intended for askers of questions?

Comment: If you're using adblock plus and have it sent to remove social media links, you'll see this behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text that you're seeing *should* read

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

with various hyperlinks to the services. Some adblockers, such as adblock plus, can be configured to [automatically remove](https://adblockplus.org/features#socialmedia) these social media links, in which case you'll see the behavior that you observed.

Comment: After learning from your answer that it is caused by some kind of adblock, it was quite easy to find some relevant posts on meta.SE: [Text error at new unanswered questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215219), [Facebook playing hide and seek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196366) or [Know someone who can answer? Share list broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214355),

Comment: That did it! I just had to disable AdBlockPlus.